# help with simple thevenin circuit and filter

Tags: circuit-analysis, filter, thevenin

I was trying to solve these excercises with thevnin circuits and filters but I really don't know what to do, could anybody help me?[image]

Comment: U1 is ineffective when in series with a current source. This means that your question is possibly flawed.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems to be homework with no effort to solve it alone.

Answer (score 0):

for the first three questions uses Laplace transform, write the matrix equations, solve and the use the inverse Laplace transform

Comment: i need each passage, cause in my professors notes he jumps many many parts, if you help me I will shout your name at my degree celebration